# Show items not in table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to return a list of brands that do not have a specific product ID.

Using the following SQL:

```
SELECT Brands
FROM AllCustomers
WHERE ProductID NOT IN (SELECT ProductID WHERE ProductID ='10235')
```

Is there a more effective way to do this as it keeps timing out?

Comment: ?? isn't this the same as  SELECT Brands FROM AllCustomers WHERE ProductID <> 10235 sample data would help clarify since it's not clear why brand would be stored in allcustomers

Answer (score 1):

Given your subquery has the explicit ProductID in the where clause and the subquery is only returning the ProductID you could simplify your query to be

```
SELECT Brands FROM AllCustomers WHERE ProductID <> '10235';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have product ID, then why are you adding sub query ?

Simply write down query like:

```
SELECT `Brands` FROM `AllCustomers` WHERE `ProductID`!='10235'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you will actually use the same syntax for other queries, you didn't specify a table in your sub-query.
Eg, if we are getting the filtered records of ProductID from the same table, it should be:

```
SELECT Brands FROM AllCustomers WHERE ProductID NOT IN (SELECT ProductID FROM AllCustomers WHERE ProductID ='10235')
```